# Suppose that a density function is given by the formula $f(x)$. Find the probability that $x$ is between $8$ and $14$.

Tags: probability, continuity

I am trying to figure out the following problem presented in my probability homework.

Suppose that a density function is given by the formula
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
 \frac{2}{108}x & \text{if}  \;\; 0 \leq x \leq 9\\
 \frac{2}{3} - \frac{2}{36}x & \text{if} \;\; 9 \leq x \leq 12 \\
 0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

Find the probability that $x$ is between $8$ and $14$.

My first solution was:
$$
   P(8 \leq X \leq 14) = \int\limits_{8}^{14} f_x(x) \hbox{ dx}
 \\ = \int\limits_{8}^{9} \frac{2}{108}x \hbox{ dx}+\int\limits_{9}^{12} \frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{36}x \hbox{ dx}+\int\limits_{12}^{14} 0 \hbox{ dx}
\\ =\left(\frac{9^2}{108} - \frac{8^2}{108}\right) +  \left( \frac{2 \cdot 12}{3} - \frac{12^2}{36} - \frac{2 \cdot 9}{3} + \frac{9^2}{36} \right) +\left( 0 - 0 \right)
\\ = \frac{17}{108} + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{11}{27}
$$

My second solution was:
$$
P(8 \leq X \leq 14) = F(14) - F(8) = 1 - \int\limits_{0}^{8} \frac{2x}{108} \hbox{ dx} - \int\limits^{0}_{-\infty} 0 \hbox{ dx} = 1 - \left( \frac{8^2}{108} - 0 \right) = \frac{44}{108} = \frac{11}{27}
$$

However, none of these solutions were accepted. Can someone help point me in the right direction to figure out how to do this problem?

**EDIT:**

The calculations are now confirmed correct, turns out there was a bug in my homework submission software.

Comment: Are you sure you copied the question correctly? Your work looks ok at first glance, but it's a bit odd that the definition of $f(x)$ has $\frac{2}{108}$ and $\frac{2}{36}$ instead of fractions in simplest form.

Comment: The calculations are correct.

Comment: Yes, I copied the question correctly. It turns out it was an error in the submission software which is why my answer was incorrect. The software randomizes the constants in the question and sometimes they look weird.

Comment: Given that your work was correct, it's probably best to post an answer to that effect, mark it as community wiki so it doesn't change reputation, wait 48 hours, then accept it. See [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6193/what-to-do-with-a-check-simplify-my-proof-type-question)meta question on handling this type of questions and the [rules](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) on self-accepting.